# Synology Personal Websites htaccess results in 403 errors

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403, synology

- Synology Server with DSM 7.1.x (recently updated from DSM 6.x and downgrading back down to DSM 6.x is not recommended by Synology)
- Webstation Enabled with HTTP back-end server: Apache HTTP Server 2.4 and PHP:
  PHP 8.0
- Personal Websites with these settings HTTP back-end server: Apache HTTP Server 2.4 and
  PHP: PHP 7.4
- Personal Websites use WordPress 5.x or 6.x which require a .htaccess file

**Problem: Personal Website .htaccess in /homes/user/www folders causes the 403 error**

Could delete .htaccess to stop 403 error but Personal Websites use WordPress which requires .htaccess - cannot just delete this file because some WordPress actions recreates the .htaccess file (such as changing Settings > Permalinks)
Newly created test user case: tmp

- homes/tmp/www folder has "users" group with 775 permissions
- homes/tmp/www/.htaccess has owner of "username" and group of "users" with 770 permissions
- homes/tmp/www/wp-config.php has owner of "username" and group of "users" with 770 permissions
- Even with permissions of 777 for ALL files in homes/tmp/www, the 403 error still exists with .htaccess
- After deleting the .htaccess and creating/publishing a new page, viewing the new page results in a 404 error.

Default .htaccess lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~username/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Even if .htaccess has no lines of code at all, the 403 error exists. So just the existence of the .htaccess file regardless of content causes a 403 error.

Anyone have ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: "Could delete .htaccess to stop 403 error" - so, what's in the `.htaccess` file? Does the site work without the `.htaccess` file, ie. without pretty permalinks?

Comment: The site works but particular WordPress actions recreates the .htaccess file such as changing permalinks, changing Settings > Reading Settings, to name other actions will trigger creating the htaccess file which contains the default WordPress lines of <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /~tmp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~tmp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I stumbled upon:

Edit the httpd2x.conf for Apache2.x (whichever is chosen for Personal Websites)

Add the following code

```
UserDir www
<Directory "var/services/homes/*/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I tried a bunch of stuff and I think the above was the trick.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  For apache2.4, on DSM 7, the file to edit is at this location: `/usr/local/etc/apache24/conf/httpd24.conf`.  I recommend you make a copy first, saved as httpd24.conf.old or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> RewriteBase /~username/
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /~username/index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

It looks like you are using [Apache per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)? If that's the case then `/~username` is not a physical directory (it's an "alias" to your user directory) and your document root is effectively `/~username/` (which really messes with root-relative URL-paths).

In which case, your `.htaccess` should be like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that I've removed the `RewriteBase` directive altogether.

However, if this is part of the WordPress code block (ie. inside `# BEGIN WordPress` ... `# END WordPress`) comment markers then WordPress is going to try and overwrite your changes unless you take additional steps to prevent this.

Comment: I made changes to the .htaccess file as you suggest. 403 error still exists. Even if .htaccess has no lines of code at all, the 403 error exists. So just the existence of the .htaccess file regardless of content causes a 403 error.

Comment: @LeoF "Even if .htaccess has no lines of code at all" - Hhhmm, that's a bit weird?! And can you view the "homepage" OK then (ie. no URL-path).

Comment: With the .personal website htaccess, the "homepage" has no problems i.e. https://example.com has no problems but the personal website https://example.com/~username has a 403 error